# How to convert List<String> to JsonNode. I want to remove elements from List

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to create a JSON Node with `"tags":"Engineering"` with

```
  JSON Example
    {"tags": ["Engineering","Pharmacy","Chemical"],
     "summary":"Science Streams",
     "produces": ["application\/json","application\/xml"]
    }
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Tags> tag = new ArrayList<Tags>();
    ArrayNode array = mapper.valueToTree(tags);
    ObjectNode objNode = mapper.valueToTree(array);
    JsonNode result = mapper.createObjectNode().set("tags", objNode );
```

When I use this I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode incompatible with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

I get a `NullPointerException` if I use

```
for(String tag:tagList)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Why are you calling `valueToTree()`?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayNode` has a remove method that takes an array index to remove. Here is a simple example that parse a JSON string, removes elements from an array in that JSON and prints it.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree("{\"tags\": [\"Engineering\",\"Pharmacy\",\"Chemical\"]}");
ArrayNode tags = (ArrayNode) tree.get("tags");
tags.remove(1);
mapper.writeTree(mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(System.out), tree);
```

If you'd like instead to replace the array with a single string value you can do:

```
((ObjectNode) tree).set("tags", new TextNode("Engineering"));
```